# Yii2 GridView focus on filtering

Tags: javascript, gridview, yii2, focus, filtering

I would like to keep focus on the last filter input field in the gridview, so when I type something in column 1, and then press **tab**, the focus jumps to the filter input field of the next column, then the page is being refreshed, and I would like it to keep the focus on the second input filter field.

I've found [an article about the same issue for Yii1.1](http://www.yiiframework.com/wiki/309/cgridview-keep-focus-on-the-control-after-filtering/), and I've tried to implement it, but unfortunately, I'm not yet so professional to achieve that. Can you please help me how can I implement the above solution or create a new one to make it work? It's quite annoying that you always have to set the focus for filtering further.

My Pjax in GridView looks like this (generated by **giiant**):

```
<?php \yii\widgets\Pjax::begin(['id' => 'pjax-main', 'enableReplaceState' => false, 'linkSelector' => '#pjax-main ul.pagination a, th a', 'clientOptions' => ['pjax:success' => 'function(){alert("yo")}']]) ?>
```

Otherwise it's a simple GridView widget.

Comment: Is it not working only for me, or does it disturb only me...? Please...

Answer (score 0):

There may be problem of "**Pjax timeout**",
Please increase timeout property of PJAX

```
Pjax::begin(['timeout'=>10000]);
```

Comment: Thanks, but unfortunately this make no difference